# Jquery change input radio button state

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I am tryign to get an alarm when user activates or deactivates a radiobutton with name `con1`

However is not working, my current code is

## html

```
<div class="form-field-box even" id="con1_field_box">
    <div class="form-display-as-box" id="con1_display_as_box">con1:</div>
    <div class="form-input-box" id="con1_input_box">
        <div class="pretty-radio-buttons">
            <label>
                <div id="uniform-field-con1-true" class="radio">    <span>
                        <input id="field-con1-true" class="radio-uniform" name="con1" value="1" type="radio">
                    </span>

                </div>active</label>
            <label>
                <div id="uniform-field-con1-false" class="radio">   <span class="checked">
                        <input id="field-con1-false" class="radio-uniform" name="con1" value="0" checked="checked" type="radio">
                    </span>

                </div>inactive</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

## js

```
$(".con1").change(function () {
    if ($("#con1").attr("checked")) {
        alert("aactive");
    } else {
        alert("inactive");
    }
});
```

What am I missing?

please take a look at [current fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qkezx010/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selecting the name (`con1`) by using the class and ID selector. Use `.radio-uniform` to refer to the radio buttons. Also, use prop() instead of attr():

```
$(".radio-uniform").change(function () {
    if ($("#field-con1-true").prop("checked")) {
        alert("aactive");
    } else {
        alert("inactive");
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qkezx010/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting the name in the way you do a class. You need to change the selector to `$("input[name=con1]")` (or you could select the class too `$(".radio-uniform")`, whichever you choose will depend on your code) and it will work fine. See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qkezx010/3/) or here:

```js
$("input[name=con1]").change(function () {
    if ($("#con1").attr("checked")) {
        alert("aactive");
    } else {
        alert("inactive");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-field-box even" id="con1_field_box">
    <div class="form-display-as-box" id="con1_display_as_box">con1:</div>
    <div class="form-input-box" id="con1_input_box">
        <div class="pretty-radio-buttons">
            <label>
                <div id="uniform-field-con1-true" class="radio"> <span>
      <input id="field-con1-true" class="radio-uniform" name="con1" value="1" type="radio">
     </span>

                </div>active</label>
            <label>
                <div id="uniform-field-con1-false" class="radio"> <span class="checked">
      <input id="field-con1-false" class="radio-uniform" name="con1" value="0" checked="checked" type="radio">
     </span>

                </div>inactive</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```